# output boolean when time is over 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT update_time FROM data order by update_time desc limit 1
```

Result:

```
'2016-07-14 11:25:15'
```

how could I compare this query with current time and output a boolean (1) when update_time is greater than 10 seconds, and output (0) when it's within 10 seconds?

Comment: you can use with "CASE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to like this:

```
select CASE WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), update_time)) > 10
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
FROM data order by update_time desc limit 1
```

Comment: I think he meant when the time value is greater then 10 , E.G. `10:20:12` is and `12:24:05` isn't.

Comment: @sagi:- Even I got confused but then I saw the title which says: `output boolean when time is over 10 seconds`

Comment: No need to use `CASE`, since comparision will return `1` or `0` anyway.

Comment: Rahul Tripathi, what I need is over 10 seconds, I shouldn't need to change anything right?

Answer (score 0):

try case when:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN update_time > Date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 10 second) THEN 
         true 
         ELSE false 
       end 
FROM   data 
ORDER  BY update_time DESC 
LIMIT  1
```